# MySQL Row in one output

Tags: php, mysql

Im pretty new to MySQl and PHP. I need some help with a small issue.

My statement is as follows:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $return_arr[] =  $row['name'];
      $return_arr[] =  $row['value'];
}
```

It outputs as follows:

```
Mr James Jones
23
```

How can I bring it together into one line? Like this:

```
Mr James Jones 23
```

Thank you

Comment: Try ... oh never mind, there's already an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Troll happens :) **Edited:** You have more votes on that comment than you could get on posting an answer :p

Comment: True, as do other things, but I won't write it on here. There may be youngsters watching. ;-) @Rikesh **Edited:** (Tip: It doesn't smell very good)

Comment: LOL, not bad eh? Yet, I never put in answers when I don't see more code. As I stated in Shankar's answer, the explanation is all in there. Questions like these usually tend to open up, what I call a "can of worms". @Rikesh I was going to put in the very same thing as Shankar, till he put in an answer, that's why I wrote that, at the very instant I was writing "`Try`"

Answer (score 3):

Do like this

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $return_arr[] =  $row['name']." ".$row['value'];
}

//print_r($return_arr); // The results gets printed as you expected or you could make use of a foreach construct as shown below.

//Printing using a foreach construct
foreach($return_arr as $k=>$v)
{
 echo $v;echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I was going to put that in a comment actually hahahaha `+1` ;-)

Comment: lol fred. Answers should not be given under comments box that is what the `comments` tip says :P

Comment: True, but I'm always afraid that it will open up a "can of worm" ;-) and many downvote because of duplicate answers. It's happened to me before :(

Comment: Editted comment above -^

Comment: Then what usually happens after is, "Now, can you show me how to print it on screen?" ;-) I lost count to how many times that's also happened to me, and in other people's answers. Just be ready "IF" it happens here too. I know you will be. ;-) Cheers

Comment: Oops! lol - Sorry about that (grin). But you know, it's true though Shankar. 9 times out of 10, that's what happens. You can never rule it out of the equation, *especially with the newbies* ;-) Then you have to pull out the "Ok, well now you have to loop over your data like this... blah blah blah..." Then it's "What's a `foreach construct`" ?!

Comment: I guess you read my mind then?... I mean "comment" hehe ;-) How's the coffee there Shankar? Had a refill yet?

Comment: Yeah gotchu. Great mate. We haven't been tweeting lately ^_^

Comment: I'm gonna have to get back on there, won't I? Soon my brother, soon. We'll catch up then :) are you on there often?

Comment: Yeah mate somewhat yes. :)

Comment: More often than me then lol! Ok, will hop on there tomorrow evening then. Will tweet you. Take care and get yourself one of those fancy coffee cups with an **anti-spill rim** ;-) You'll thank me for it. ciao - **Edit:** Btw, I was "right".

Answer (score 3):

Use [`implode`](http://php.net/function.implode) to join the array elements:

```
echo implode(' ', $return_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this,

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $return_arr[] =  $row['name']. ' '.$row['value'];
}
```

it will work.
And if you want any other help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is handling it inside your mysql query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' ', value) as name_and_value FROM ....
```

Than you can use

```
$row['name_and_value']
```

in your php code.

Comment: Thats great, working perfectly. Only question is how do I add and additional space or even text between the 2 outputs? Mr James Jones 23, to Mr James Jones "IS" 23

Comment: You can change blankspace between two fields to any character or string. Example SELECT CONCAT(name, 'add any string here', value) as name_and_value FROM ....

Comment: CONCAT means Concatenation. So php equvalent of this sql would be  **$name.' '.$value**. You can also add any number of fields/strings inside concat like **CONCAT(field1,' IS ',{$aphpvariable},' but ', field2, field3)**